# If a user has access to “execute” an stored procedure, but does not have “insert” access to the specific table, will this stored procedure fail?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, user-permissions

I'm having issues with this question. In my opinion, if the user has execute permission to the procedure, he doesn't need insert permission to the table.

This is the stored procedure:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014
GO
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
Create PROCEDURE CustomerService.add_RepID
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @repid int,
  @SupervisorID int
  with EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
  insert into CustomerService.Reps values (@repID, @SupervisorID);
END
```

Comment: are you unable set up this scenario locally and try it yourself?

Comment: From [`Execute As`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "Only the user that the module is running as must have permissions on the objects accessed by the module." Does the owner of the SP have the ability to `insert` on the target table?